# Where is the start button in Alcatel Idol 2 (6037)

Tags: navigation

I've just bought Android Smartphone Alcatel Idol 2 ( 6037 ) but I don't have the button that display all the apps.

I've tried and tried, and I've seen some screenshots in the web with this button, but I can't get it working! Any idea?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your home screen? Alcatel phones usually have a grid-like icon in the bottom right to display the all apps screen, next to the messaging app.

Comment: Resolved installing a custom launcher

Comment: If you solved your issue, you might wish to *answer* your own question (that's perfectly fine) and accept that answer thereafter – so other affected users can see there's a solution. If you do so, please add a few more words – one-liners without explanation might be hard to some readers ;) Thanks!